# Is there an action for save_menu and/or update_menu?

Tags: theme-development, menus, theme-options, actions

I want to "save" my menus into transients. I want to update those when there's been any changes to the menus via the admin custom menus. I've looked for an action but can't see to find anything. Perhaps I missed the obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_update_nav_menu?version=3.5&file=wp-includes/nav-menu.php :

```
do_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', $menu_id, $menu_data );
```

Consequently, a nav menu is a custom post type, as are its menu items, so all of the usual hooks for publish/save/update/trash apply

Comment: Ha! Thx. I was searching for save, not update. Good stuff. Thank you @TomJNowell

Comment: If it's the correct answer could you mark it as correct?